# Can we have many coordinator nodes at one time in Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, parallel-processing, nodes, distributed

Hope this is the right place to ask!

I am trying to set up a cluster with spark, cassandra and one more external tool. So, the external tool is executed in parallel across the cluster with the help of spark(pipe command) and this tool has the ability to store straight into cassandra database(see picture below) through a simple sql Insert command. This means that in every node the results are send from the external tool of the node straight to the cassandra of the node.

My wild guess/doubt/question is that each of these nodes will act as coordinator node and will be responsible for destributing/sending the data to other nodes according to the primary/partition key at the same time. Is that right? If not...what will happen?

[external_tool_to_cassandra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl6wB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the Cassandra nodes can act as a coordinator. If your tool is correctly configured to use TokenAwarePolicy, your tool should choose for each request a replica as a coordinator, avoiding a few extra network hop. If you insert in Batch, try to batch together data with the same partition key.

Note that in your diagram, you will get better performance you write directly from Spark to Cassandra. You can use the spark-cassandra-connector for that.

Comment: Yes, all the nodes can be coordinators. But can they be at the same time? so, the answer is yes! Also, by saying tool I guess you mean generally the tool and not the external tool! 

So basically I don't have to configure something because as they say in datastax: "If you don’t explicitly configure the policy, you get the default, which is a datacenter-aware, token-aware policy". I do not use batch, just insert.

The processing is bassically done by the external tool, spark only pipes a filepath to a shell script(.sh) with which the external tool is executed in every node.

Comment: @Des0lat0r No you can't have multiple coordinators for one request if that's what you're asking. The client will pick one of the nodes in your Cassandra cluster and use that as a coordinator. Which node becomes the coordinator depends on what load balancing policy you use.

Comment: For one request yes it makes sense to have one coordinator. But basically I am talking about multiple write requests(like in the picture above), one from each node at the same time.  Is that possible?? This happens because within the external tool in each node there is an "Insert" command(in a loop) which means that many insert commands take place at the same time(concurrently) in each one of the nodes.

Comment: Yes it is possible to make multiple requests at the same time from different clients and these clients can all use different coordinator. But which coordinator they use is still up to the load balancing policy you use. If you want some specific behaviour then you can write your own  policy.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your time! But, let me be more specific. Basically, there is only one client request that generates many write-requests. The user wants to process a set of files, while we want to process what he asked and also store the results in cassandra. Specifically one file per node is processed by the external tool. This processing produces different results in every node which we want to store in cassandra in parallel. So, my guess is that every node will act as a coordinator at the same time and send the results to the corresponding node according to the token range. Right??